# Elastic Search - Java BoolQuery API should filter which are all not matching

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have the following fields & values in my documents and am trying to fetch `ids` which are all not matching with my input query.

Please find the documents that am having in my elastic search indexes.

```
id      region
1001    MEA
1002    MEA
1003    EUR
1004    MEA
1005    EUR
1006    AF
```

I want to filter ids which is not matching with the region `MEA`.

Am expecting like below results.

```
id      region
1003    EUR
1005    EUR
1006    AF
```

As of now, am using the below query

```
 QueryBuilder regionQB = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("catalog_product_id", catalog_product_id_list))
                    .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("region_id", "MEA"));
```

Which is giving all the matching ( region `MEA`) results.

Answer (score 1):

For filtering ids which are not matching with the region 'MEA'
instead of using `filter()`, you can use **mustNot()**. 
Please refer below code,

```
QueryBuilder regionQB = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("catalog_product_id", catalog_product_id_list))
                    .mustNot(QueryBuilders.termQuery("region_id", "MEA"));
```